# Can't set Ansible fact as integer

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to extract the major distro version (which `ansible_facts` holds as a string) and store it as an integer for later `<` or `>` comparison to an integer.  When I do this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    distromajor: "{{ ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] | int }}"
```

I find `distromajor` holds `"7"` instead of `7`.
So later comparisons fail. In fact, the only way I can get it to work is to compare like this:

```yaml
(distromajor|int >=6) and (distromajor|int <= 8)
```

Is this expected behaviour?
Why can I not save the distro major version as an int?

The closest [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245699/ansible-how-to-do-arithmetic-for-integer-variable-in-set-fact-module) does not explain why a later integer comparison **fails** without reconverting the `distromajor` variable to integer at time of comparison.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible: How to do arithmetic for integer variable in set\_fact module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245699/ansible-how-to-do-arithmetic-for-integer-variable-in-set-fact-module)

Comment: No.  I saw that before but it does not explain why later comparison fails unless I AGAIN convert to int at time of comparison

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Q: *"**Is this expected behavior?**"*

A: Yes. This is the expected behavior, in Ansible.

---

Q: *"**Why can I not save the distro major version as an int?**"*

A: Ansible decided you can't (todo: reference to source code needed). In [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/#Introduction), there are three basic primitives:

- mappings (hashes/dictionaries)
- sequences (arrays/lists)
- scalars (strings/numbers)

As you can see, the scalars are both strings and numbers. But, for some reason unknown to me, Ansible decided that any `"{{ scalar }}"` expression can return only *string* or *boolean*. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        distromajor: "{{ ansible_facts['distribution_major_version']|int }}"
    - debug:
        var: distromajor
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ distromajor|type_debug }}"
```

gives a string despite the explicit conversion to integer, as you've already found out

```yaml
  distromajor: '20'
  msg: AnsibleUnsafeText
```

---

Update.

If you want to keep a variable as integer put it into a dictionary. For example,

```yaml
  my_dict_yaml: |
    distromajor: {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}
  my_dict: "{{ my_dict_yaml|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_dict:
    distromajor: 20
  my_dict.distromajor|type_debug: int
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_dict_yaml: |
      distromajor: {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}
    my_dict: "{{ my_dict_yaml|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - setup:
        gather_subset: distribution_major_version
    - debug:
        var: ansible_distribution_major_version
    - debug:
        var: ansible_distribution_major_version|type_debug

    - debug:
        var: my_dict
    - debug:
        var: my_dict.distromajor|type_debug
```