# Ansible: Error "not supported between instances of ''AnsibleUnsafeText'' and ''int'"

Tags: ansible, operator-keyword

I have below Ansible playbook.

```yaml
  - name: free space
    cisco.nxos.nxos_command:
      commands: "dir | grep -i 'free'"
    register: free_space_out


  - name: Set fact for free space
    set_fact:
      free_space: "{{ free_space_out.stdout[0].split(' ')[0] | int }}"

  - name: free space msg
    debug:
      msg: "Available free space: {{ free_space }}"

  - name: Validate free space
    assert:
      that:
      - free_space > 5000000
      success_msg: "SUCCESS"
      fail_msg: "FAILURE"
```

The last task gives an error:

> `"''>'' not supported between instances of ''AnsibleUnsafeText'' and ''int''"`

How can I fix it?

Comment: `- free_space | int > 5000000`. Registering a fact via templating makes it a string.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69109779/2123530