# Getting a string results instead of int in ansible, Error"TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"

Tags: python, ansible

I am using a task with loop in order to calculate the total size of the disk capacity used in RAID configuration So thre is no issue with calcultaing the capacity, the issue is that my results is being treated as string type instead of int. So once I collected the variable results and used in other task (RAID Creation) i'am getting this error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"

```
- name: Group RAID1 physical drives by location
  set_fact:
    physical_drives_int: "{{  physical_drives.ilo_storage.GetPhysicalDrives.msg.physical_drives['array_controller_0'] | map(attribute='CapacityGB') | map('int') | list }}"

- name: Count RAID1 Disk Total Capacity
  vars:
    total_capacity_R1: 0
  loop: "{{  physical_drives_int }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item }}"
  when: item == 300
  set_fact:
    total_capacity_R1: "{{ (total_capacity_R1 | int  + item | int) | int }}"
```

below the the registred output physical_drives registred

```
{
  "ilo_storage": {
    "ret": true,
    "GetPhysicalDrives": {
      "msg": {
        "physical_drives": {
          "array_controller_0": [
            {
              "Id": "0",
              "BlockSizeBytes": 512,
              "CapacityGB": 300,
              "CapacityLogicalBlocks": 585937500,
              "CapacityMiB": 286102,
              "CarrierApplicationVersion": "11",
              "CarrierAuthenticationStatus": "OK",
              "CurrentTemperatureCelsius": 32,
              "Description": "HPE Smart Storage Disk Drive View",
              "DiskDriveStatusReasons": [
                "None"
              ],
              "DiskDriveUse": "Raw",
              "EncryptedDrive": false,
              "FirmwareVersion": {
                "Current": {
                  "VersionString": "HPD5"
                }
              },
              "InterfaceSpeedMbps": 12000,
              "InterfaceType": "SAS",
              "LegacyBootPriority": "Primary",
              "Location": "1I:1:1",
              "LocationFormat": "ControllerPort:Box:Bay",
              "MaximumTemperatureCelsius": 46,
              "MediaType": "HDD",
              "Model": "EG000300JWEBF",
              "Name": "HpeSmartStorageDiskDrive",
              "PowerOnHours": null,
              "RotationalSpeedRpm": 10500,
              "SSDEnduranceUtilizationPercentage": null,
              "SerialNumber": "************",
              "Status": {
                "Health": "OK",
                "State": "Enabled"
              },
              "UncorrectedReadErrors": 0,
              "UncorrectedWriteErrors": 0
            },
            {
              "Id": "1",
              "BlockSizeBytes": 512,
              "CapacityGB": 300,
              "CapacityLogicalBlocks": 585937500,
              "CapacityMiB": 286102,
              "CarrierApplicationVersion": "11",
              "CarrierAuthenticationStatus": "OK",
              "CurrentTemperatureCelsius": 32,
              "Description": "HPE Smart Storage Disk Drive View",
              "DiskDriveStatusReasons": [
                "None"
              ],
              "DiskDriveUse": "Raw",
              "EncryptedDrive": false,
              "FirmwareVersion": {
                "Current": {
                  "VersionString": "HPD5"
                }
              },
              "InterfaceSpeedMbps": 12000,
              "InterfaceType": "SAS",
              "LegacyBootPriority": "Primary",
              "Location": "1I:1:2",
              "LocationFormat": "ControllerPort:Box:Bay",
              "MaximumTemperatureCelsius": 48,
              "MediaType": "HDD",
              "Model": "EG000300JWEBF",
              "Name": "HpeSmartStorageDiskDrive",
              "PowerOnHours": null,
              "RotationalSpeedRpm": 10500,
              "SSDEnduranceUtilizationPercentage": null,
              "SerialNumber": "**********",
              "Status": {
                "Health": "OK",
                "State": "Enabled"
              },
              "UncorrectedReadErrors": 0,
              "UncorrectedWriteErrors": 0
            },
            {
              "Id": "2",
              "BlockSizeBytes": 512,
              "CapacityGB": 600,
              "CapacityLogicalBlocks": 1172123568,
              "CapacityMiB": 572325,
              "CarrierApplicationVersion": "11",
              "CarrierAuthenticationStatus": "OK",
              "CurrentTemperatureCelsius": 33,
              "Description": "HPE Smart Storage Disk Drive View",
              "DiskDriveStatusReasons": [
                "None"
              ],
              "DiskDriveUse": "Raw",
              "EncryptedDrive": false,
              "FirmwareVersion": {
                "Current": {
                  "VersionString": "HPD8"
                }
              },
              "InterfaceSpeedMbps": 12000,
              "InterfaceType": "SAS",
              "LegacyBootPriority": "Primary",
              "Location": "1I:1:3",
              "LocationFormat": "ControllerPort:Box:Bay",
              "MaximumTemperatureCelsius": 48,
              "MediaType": "HDD",
              "Model": "EG000600JWJNP",
              "Name": "HpeSmartStorageDiskDrive",
              "PowerOnHours": null,
              "RotationalSpeedRpm": 10000,
              "SSDEnduranceUtilizationPercentage": null,
              "SerialNumber": "*************",
              "Status": {
                "Health": "OK",
                "State": "Enabled"
              },
              "UncorrectedReadErrors": 0,
              "UncorrectedWriteErrors": 0
            },
            {
          ]
        },
        "physical_drives_count": 8
      },
      "ret": true
    }
  },
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
      "category": [
        "Systems"
      ],
      "command": [
        "GetPhysicalDrives"
      ],
      "baseuri": "*.*.*.*",
      "username": "***********",
      "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
      "timeout": 60,
      "auth_token": null,
      "cert_file": null,
      "key_file": null,
      "raid_details": null,
      "logical_drives_names": null
    }
  },
  "_ansible_no_log": null,
  "changed": false
}
```

the result of the task count the capacity

```
{
  "ansible_facts": {
    "total_capacity_R1": "600"
  },
  "_ansible_no_log": null,
  "changed": false,
  "item": 300,
  "ansible_loop_var": "item",
  "_ansible_item_label": 300
}
```

this is the radi creation Task:

```
- name: Create logical drives with particular physical drives when username and password are defined
  block:
    - hpe.ilo.ilo_storage:
        category: Systems
        command: CreateLogicalDrivesWithParticularPhysicalDrives
        baseuri: "{{ baseuri }}"
        username: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        raid_details:
          - LogicalDriveName: "LD1"
            Raid: "Raid1"
            CapacityGB: "{{ total_capacity_R1 | int }}"
            DataDrives: "{{ datadrive_locations_raid1 }}"
```

error Message:

line 1253, in check_physical_drives\nTypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'\n"

I wonder if someone faced a similar issue and if there is another way to get disk capacity results in int i'm all ears

thanks in advance

I am pretty aware that set_fact always re-cast the type to string , tried to "{{ my_variable }}" | int with no success

Comment: Please don't repost (and delete) your [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78061046/getting-a-string-results-instead-of-int-in-ansible-errortypeerror-not-sup) to bypass the closure. **Edit** them to resolve the closure issues and send them to the reopen votes review queue.

Comment: ok sorry for that, but the review took much time even after resolving the closure issues

Answer (score 0):

> ***How to convert a string var into integer? ... I tried with `| int` ...***

Right, that's the correct approach of [Forcing the data type](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-the-data-type) and you are almost there.

Please take note the [`set_fact` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html#notes)

> *Using the setting will restrict k=v to strings ...*

This means a task

```yaml
   - ansible.builtin.set_fact:
     new_variable: "{{ variable | int }}"
```

will end up with a string.

> ***I need to convert/cast into integer in my playbook.***

You just need to cast to integer when necessary but not before. A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    total_capacity_R1: "600"

  tasks:

  - name: Show value
    debug:
      msg: "Total capacity is {{ total_capacity_R1 | int }} and of type {{ total_capacity_R1 | int | type_debug }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show value] **************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Total capacity is 600 and of type int
```

That's how you would use your variable in the other task (`- name: RAID Creation`) and prevent an `TypeError: ... not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`.

> ***How can I sum up my capacity?***

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    total_capacity_R1: "600"
    add_on: "200"

  tasks:

  - name: Sum up capacity
    debug:
      msg: "{{ total_capacity_R1 | int + add_on | int }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Sum up capacity] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '800'
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [Can't set Ansible fact as integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69109779/6771046)

Comment: So if I' understood you well , set-fact will always give me a sring variable
but how can I do  my sum capacity as above using loop , Since i've already use debug and registered and end up with dict type

Comment: "_`set_fact` will always give me a string variable_", right, that's how it is.

Comment: in fact i've done as you said and used | int on the RAID creation Task and I am still getting the same error

Comment: Neither you showing your RAID creation task, nor what's the input of it or what's the full output and full error message. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for me it isn't reproducible at all, just a syntax error and I can only give basic information and hints.

Comment: for the input i've already shared with you the json I amusing to count the disk total capacity 
and I have modified my description with the task of raid creation

Comment: The error message `line 1253, in check_physical_drives\nTypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'\n"` belongs not to the tasks you have shown. Neither one of them contains a string `check_physical_drives` nor has one a comparssion less than `<`. For where that is coming from was already asked in the former now deleted question within a comment.

Comment: I think this is the python module which is calling 
check this and start from the line 1253 :  https://github.com/HewlettPackard/ilo-ansible-collection/blob/main/plugins/module_utils/ilo_oem_utils.py 

"ilo/plugins/module_utils/ilo_oem_utils.py\", line 1253, in check_physical_drives\nTypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'\n","

Comment: That could be a possible cause. Unfortunately I haven't found a documentation or generic example for the module `hpe.ilo.ilo_storage`, as well no hardware to test. Therefore I can't follow up on this.